# How to Detect Almost Duplicate Locations in a Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, geolocation

I have a Pandas dataframe containing geocoded addresses. I'd like to detect any addresses that have *almost* the same latitude and longitude e.g. are within 0.0001 degree of both the latitude and longitude. I'd like to record the results in a new field: "Possible Duplicate", or "Unique".

Here's an example. Given the following:

```
ID  Latitude    Longitude
A   31.26418    -86.36509
B   44.52456    -79.52941
C   45.48913    -87.77436
D   54.03550    -85.87823
E   37.05611    -83.53684
F   53.26993    -85.28143
G   45.48910    -87.77440
H   51.60626    -83.33459
```

The output should be:

```
ID  Latitude    Longitude   Status
A   31.26418    -86.36509   Unique
B   44.52456    -79.52941   Unique
C   45.48913    -87.77436   Possible Duplicate
D   54.03550    -85.87823   Unique
E   37.05611    -83.53684   Unique
F   53.26993    -85.28143   Unique
G   45.48910    -87.77440   Possible Duplicate
H   51.60626    -83.33459   Unique
```

Note: this is not a combination type problem like: [Detecting almost duplicate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42958689/detecting-almost-duplicate-rows)

What's the most pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting almost duplicate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42958689/detecting-almost-duplicate-rows)

Comment: Perform `drop_duplicates()` only on the targeted columns. For specific help, support your problem with more description, provide sample data, your way to tackle and expected output. Also have a look at [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @RahulAgarwal doesn't seem to be a duplicate since neither of the solutions provided for that question can be applied to this problem

Comment: @meW Example added - Thanks

Comment: I can understand that `G` can be a possible duplicate of `C` but can you explain how `C` is a duplicate and of which row is it a duplicate of?

Comment: @meW I need it to show *any* row that may have a duplicate e.g. `C` is a duplicate of `G` and vice-versa, `G` is a duplicate of `C`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can round the latitude and longitude values up to 4 decimal places (as you suggested till 0.0001) and then proceed with checking duplicates.

```
df['Status'] = 'Unique'
df.loc[df[df.loc[:, ['Latitude', 'Longitude']].round(4).duplicated(keep=False)].index, 'Status'] = 'Possible duplicate'
```

Comment: Brilliant! That's a truly amazing one line of code!