# How to detect which column has different values in almost duplicate rows in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a DataFrame with around 10,000 rows, of which around 1,000 rows are either duplicates or almost duplicates.

Here is a simplified example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'App': ['Slack', 'Candy Bomb', 'Facebook', 'Candy Bomb', 'Slack', 'Slack', 'Facebook'],
                  'Category': ['Business', 'Game', 'Social', 'Family', 'Business', 'Business', 'Social'],
                  'Rating': [4.4, 4.6, 4.1, 4.6, 4.4, 4.4, 3.9],
                  'Reviews': [1000, 30000, 5000, 30000, 950, 950, 5000]})
```

Output

```py
    App         Category    Rating   Reviews
0   Slack       Business    4.4      1000
1   Candy Bomb  Game        4.6      30000
2   Facebook    Social      4.1      5000
3   Candy Bomb  Family      4.6      30000
4   Slack       Business    4.4      950
5   Slack       Business    4.4      950
6   Facebook    Social      3.9      5000
```

For example, the `Reviews` column of *Slack* has different values:

```py
    App     Category    Rating    Reviews
0   Slack   Business    4.4       1000
4   Slack   Business    4.4       950
5   Slack   Business    4.4       950
```

Expected output: *Reviews*

The `Category` column of *Candy Bomb* has different values:

```py
    App           Category    Rating    Reviews
1   Candy Bomb    Game        4.6       30000
3   Candy Bomb    Family      4.6       30000
```

Expected output: *Category*

**How do I find the column with different values for each of the apps?** (so that I can decide which row to keep and remove.)

I tried this:

```py
target_row = df[df['App'] == 'Candy Bomb']

columns = df.columns

for column in columns:
    dupl_result = target_row.duplicated(subset=column)
    if dupl_result.iloc[0] == dupl_result.iloc[1]:
        print(column)
```

Output:

```
Category
```

However, the code above only works for apps with **two** almost duplicate rows, but not for other amount of rows for large scale. I tried to modify this code in multiple ways but it still didn't work.

Are there any simpler or better ways to solve this?

**Note**: My question is different from [How to Detect Almost Duplicate Locations in a Pandas Dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867061/how-to-detect-almost-duplicate-locations-in-a-pandas-dataframe) and [Detecting almost duplicate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42958689/detecting-almost-duplicate-rows?noredirect=1&lq=1).

---

Update #01: Make the question clearer by emphasizing it.

Update #02: Make the expected output clearer

Comment: Do you want to split by app? `for app, subdf in df.groupby('App'): print(f'App: {app}\n{subdf}')`

Comment: No. I just want to find the columns where the values are different for each of the apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not fully clear, but maybe something like:

```
for app, subdf in df.groupby('App'):
    print(f'App: {app}')
    m = subdf.ne(subdf.iloc[0]).any()
    if m.any():
        print(f"  Varying columns: {','.join(df.columns[m])}")
    else:
        print('  No difference')
```

Output:

```
App: Candy Bomb
  Varying columns: Category
App: Facebook
  Varying columns: Rating
App: Slack
  Varying columns: Reviews
```

Comment: Your code solved my question in an elegant way! May I know which part of my question is not clear, so that I could make it better next time?

Comment: @SPW I didn't know which exact output you expected, glad it worked for you ;)